# Unable to deploy my first Azure Spring Cloud application

Tags: spring-boot, azure-spring-cloud, azure-java-tools, azure-spring-boot

I'm trying the QuickStart to running A Spring Boot in Azure Spring Cloud https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-quickstart?tabs=IntelliJ&pivots=programming-language-java

I download the spring starter with associated jars, but when it starts up I get a bunch of errors

```
Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2020-10-08 23:20:47.012 ERROR [,,,] 32573 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error. endpoint=DefaultEndpoint{ serviceUrl='http://localhost:8761/eureka/}

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.25.jar:1.9.25]
```

How do I stop this from happening, has anyone had luck with the Microsoft Spring Boot Quickstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to run the app locally? if that is the case this error is expected as the eureka server hosted by Azure Spring Cloud is not reachable from your dev machine. Please deploy the app to Azure Spring Cloud.